# Calculate overlap for two lists of rectangles

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Given two lists R1 and R2 of axis-aligned rectangles. The lists have length n and m, respectively. For each rectangle from R1, I'd like to know by how much it overlaps with each of the rectangles in R2. As measure for overlap I'd use intersection over union (IoU).

Question: Do I have to make n x m comparisons or is there a faster way?

All of the solutions I found focused on the problem where you only have a single list of rectangles and not two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) for one of the lists and check rectangles from another list for intersection with r-tree items.

In this case you lower complexity from `O(n*m)` to `O(nlogn+mlogn)`